# What is the significance of 1000/60 in RequestAnimationFrame polyfill

Tags: javascript, css

I was just going through the source of vivus.js and came across the following line of code:

```
requestAnimFrame = (function () {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    function(/* function */ callback){
      return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  );
})();
```

now ofcource i run the latest version of chrome and the first condition is true and is what is what is actually returned  but what i am really concerned about is the last condition I.E.

```
function(/* function */ callback){
    return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
}
```

why is it `1000 / 60` ? i understand why the setTimeout is used , but what does 1000/60 really do ? can anybody explain this part ?

P.S. i know its a mathematical question, but since it involves substantial amount of code , i had to post on SO.

Thank you.

Comment: `1000` is 1 second in milliseconds, dividing it by `60` gives you the time in milliseconds for which a frame needs to appear to achieve ~60 fps

Comment: @DJDavid98 Your comment is clear and understandable, and would serve well as an answer.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative I'm not here to farm imaginary internet points for something as simple as this

Comment: mmmm, lovely internet points.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Cool, good to hear. But that's not what I meant. I loaded up the question because it appeared unanswered, however, had a perfectly clear and viable answer in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

60 frames per second is the minimum frame rate at which most humans perceive something as animating smoothly.

Hence running every 60th of 1000ms (1s).

Comment: Console Peasants are content with 30fps